# Python FutureWarning. new syntax?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python swears at my syntax, says soon it will be impossible to write like that. Can you please tell me how to change the function?

```
def cleaning_name1(data):
    """Cleaning name1 minus brand + space+articul + art + round brackets """
    data['name1'] = data['name1'].str.split('артикул').str[0]
    data['name1'] = data['name1'].str.split('арт').str[0]
    data['name1'] = (data['name1'].str.replace('brand ', '', )
                     .str.replace(' ', '', ).str.replace('(', '', ).str.replace(')', '', ))
    return data
```

Comment: There are a million ways to change the function. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: She is operating normally. But now python began to warn about future changes. I would like to know how to avoid this.

FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version. In addition, single character regular expressions will *not* be treated as literal strings when regex=True.
  data['name1'] = (data['name1'].str.replace('brand ', '', )

Comment: This isn't *Python* raising the warnings, but Pandas(?). It's not syntax that's changing, but rather the API provided by Pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, `.str.replace()` defaults to `regex=True`. This is planned to change to `regex=False` in the future. You should make this explicit in your calls.

```
    data['name1'] = data['name1'].str.replace('brand ', '', regex=False)
                     .str.replace(' ', '', regex=False).str.replace('(', '', regex=False ).str.replace(')', '', regex=False)
```

Although in your case, it would be better to use a regular expression, so you can do all the replacements in a single call:

```
    data['name1'] = data['name1'].str.replace('brand|[ ()]', '', regex=True)
```